# USB webcam not working in 20.04

Tags: usb, webcam, logitech

I have an old Logitech USB camera that was working in 18.04 but after an installation of 20.04 it does not work. Here is what I can say after googling around.

/dev/video seems OK:

```
ls -la /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 set 13 12:05 /dev/video0
```

my user belongs to video group.

I tried with lsusb and the webcam is there:

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c505 Logitech, Inc. Cordless Mouse+Keyboard Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:08d7 Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Communicate STX
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But running cheese I get a black window with °No device found° message. And here is the output on console:

```
** Message: 13:05:27.575: cheese-application.vala:214: Error during camera setup: No device found


(cheese:3860): cheese-CRITICAL **: 13:05:27.582: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

(cheese:3860): GLib-CRITICAL **: 13:05:27.582: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cheese:3860): GLib-CRITICAL **: 13:05:27.582: g_variant_ref_sink: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:3860): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 13:05:27.582: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:3860): GLib-CRITICAL **: 13:05:27.582: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:3860): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 13:05:27.582: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

(cheese:3860): GLib-CRITICAL **: 13:05:27.582: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

** (cheese:3860): CRITICAL **: 13:05:27.582: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed
```

I removed cheese and installed guvcview and with it I can see my webcam working. Now, I need to make it working with Skype. Any idea?

Cheers,
Gianni

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webcam mounted on /dev/video0 and usable by VLC but nothing else detects it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220656/webcam-mounted-on-dev-video0-and-usable-by-vlc-but-nothing-else-detects-it)