# Trying to get a webcam to work under Ubuntu Studio 20.04

Tags: video, webcam, uvc

I've been trying for a while to get a webcam to work with my Linux installation. After being unsuccessful with an old HP webcam which didn't show up in the `/dev/` directory, even though its microphone was working and could be used by Chromium, I purchased a Logitech HD C270, which is a model listed as supported by the UVC driver project. However, I'm still not getting a picture under Chromium or Cheese. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using `guvcview` instead of Cheese? This one has more options.

Comment: Just tried guvcview with the Logitech C270. "No video device found."

Comment: Are you using a USB2 or USB3 slot? I think this camera is supposed to use a USB2 slot.

Comment: USB2. Still no success.

Comment: Does it show up when you run `lsusb`?

Comment: It's just a stretch but you could try installing `libuvc0` to see if that helps.

Comment: lsusb output: Bus 002 Device 008: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270. Installed libuvc0. Still "No device found" in Cheese and "No video device found" in guvcview.

Comment: Plug the device in and reboot. Sometimes this allows permission over external devices.

Comment: Rebooted with device plugged in. No change.

Comment: If the camera is listed in `/dev` you can try using `vlc`. If the device is `video1` you can run `vlc v4l2:///dev/video1`  If this works, then please refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1220670/167115).

Comment: Please let me know if this is the solution so that I can mark this as a duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: If it's showing up in /dev/ I'm not recognizing it. There is no "videoX" device shown, although the camera is still showing up in lsusb. There is a "dev/usb" directory which shows two "hiddevX" devices, but I'm not sure what they are.