# Labtech webcam shows black screen

Tags: webcam

I have an old Labtech webcam, and it shows only a black screen.

`lsusb` gaves me:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:0929 Logitech, Inc. Labtec Webcam Pro
```

Also:

```
ls -la /dev/video0 
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Feb 16 13:36 /dev/video0
```

When starting cheese, it says, no device found.

Skype is showing only a black screen.

Can anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: Does this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220656/webcam-mounted-on-dev-video0-and-usable-by-vlc-but-nothing-else-detects-it/1220670#1220670  work for you?